# iOS UILabel and avoiding clipping of diacritics with custom font

Tags: ios, fonts, uilabel, diacritics, clipping

First of all, there are many questions on StackOverflow, but none that fully answer this question.

The problem is mainly, but most likely not limited to, Thai and Arabic diacritics when rendered with a custom Latin-only font, using the text property of a UILabel. Which is also intrinsically sized in an auto-layout. I've already done everything Apple suggests, playing with the settings mentioned in their documentation, WWDC videos, as well as questions on StackOverflow (e.g. clipsToBounds = NO, etc.). Keep in mind, only my custom font setup clips in my scenario, not the iOS system font (.SF-UIDisplay), and not even the iOS system provided Helvetica or Helvetic Neue. The custom font has been checked and rechecked, and at this point the conclusion, iOS is the anomaly across all platforms, even macOS. To be even clearer, the same clipping behavior as the custom font can be seen with SF Pro, a font provided by Apple themselves here: https://developer.apple.com/fonts/

This question is about the most proper, least intrusive, and most complete way to do what is necessary to not clip diacritics. Meaning, how would you do this, ideally, from scratch.

All of my font research and test runs have led all those involved in this problem to believe that Apple has implemented special treatment specifically for their system fonts in UILabel, to avoid diacritic clipping. So making that an assumption, I'm also assuming the font is ok, and I'm looking for solutions that do not involve editing the font.

In my tries to use the font, the first thing to go wrong was vertical clipping of the ascender diacritics of Thai glyphs:

```
นื้ทั้มูHello
```

This means the glyphs of the font Thonburi when they cascade from the custom Latin-only font. The fix from this point, was to use a custom font only for Thai without any Latin characters, so it could be defined as the primary font, and cascade to the previously mentioned Latin-only custom font. After all this, the custom Thai font still has horizontal clipping issues on diacritics that come at the end of the text:

```
Worldฟล์
```

So now I am at a loss for anything further that font management puppetry can do (though still open to suggestions), and I am moving on to more code-centric fixes. I've seen quite a few questions and answers mentioning subclassing UILabel, but I'd like to know what this would look like that could accomplish what I've described.

I'd also like to know if just opting out of UILabel would be an option for anyone. Meaning would writing something from the ground up with TextKit be worth it to avoid all these bugs that seem to only plague iOS, and specifically UILabel.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue with a custom font and diacritics on Swedish letters (namely Å). Did you resolve your issue without subclassing UILabel?

Comment: I did not solve this issue, and still waiting for responses.

Comment: Could the solution described in this blog post be of any help? http://www.andyyardley.com/2012/04/24/custom-ios-fonts-and-how-to-fix-the-vertical-position-problem/ I have yet to try it myself.

Comment: I’ve exhausted all avenues related to fonts. The custom font is a pretty high profile font, made by a world renown foundry. That’s why I compared it to SF Pro, which is provided by Apple, and has the same issues. This is not an issue with the font. To point out one more reason why its not the font, I found the Helvética font ttc file that is used in iOS simulator. I edited the font renaming the font family and faces, I used that as a custom font, with all metrics intact from the original Helvética, and it has the exact same clipping issues as my font. I have not tried replacing the iOS font.

Comment: What I meant was that I have not tried replacing the iOS Helvética with another font to see if iOS treats it differently like I suspect it will.

Answer (score 3):

At first I thought this was a problem with the framework but it's not, it's just a strict enforcement of a font's metrics. And in probably everything but web/app development, fonts are not rendered so strictly, which is why this problem rarely comes up. Fonts have a number of metrics that tell the program rendering it onto the screen how to render it, most importantly how to handle padding. And `UILabel` (and `UITextField`, and likely others) applies these metrics strictly. And the problem for us is that some fonts are very decorative and are often too thick or oblique to fit perfectly into the square canvas that each character must fit into (this is especially the case with accents, like umlauts). This isn't a problem outside of web/app development because when a character doesn't fit into its canvas, like a very thick, wide, and oblique `W`, the program just shows it anyway, and that's why a low-hanging `g` might spill into the line below it. But if that `g` was rendered in a single-line `UILabel`, because of how strict the font-metric enforcement is in iOS, that low-handing `g` is clipped.

Subclassing `UILabel` (in the case of `UILabel`) and overriding its `intrinsicContentSize` to add some extra padding is not a good idea, on further research. For one, it's kind of hacky, but more importantly, it produces constraint warnings in the debugger. The true fix, and the only acceptable fix AFAIK, is to edit the font's metrics.

Download a program like Glyphs (https://glyphsapp.com/), open the font, open the `Font's Info`, and in the `Masters` tab, give the font the proper ascender and descender values. To best understand how these values work, open the San Francisco font in the program and see how Apple did it (it's the font they made specifically for macOS and iOS development). As a side note, if you use this app, when you're editing the font's info, go into the `Features` tab as well, delete all of the features (using the minus icon in the lower left) and hit `Update` to let the program manage the font's features for you.

The last hurdle is clipping at the leading edge (not the top and bottom) which the ascender and descender metrics don't address. You can use the Glyphs program to edit the canvas size of individual characters to make sure they all fit but that changes the complexion of the font because it changes the character spacing too noticeably. For this problem, I think the best solution is to simply use attributed strings for your labels and text fields. And that's because attributed strings let you safely edit padding without hacking into intrinsic sizes. An example:

```
someLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Done", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.blackItalic(size: 26), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle.kItalicCenter])
```

For convenience, I extended `NSMutableParagraphStyle` since I use this font all over:

```
extension NSMutableParagraphStyle {
    static var kItalicCenter: NSMutableParagraphStyle {
        let s = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        s.alignment = .center
        s.firstLineHeadIndent = 2
        s.headIndent = 2
        return s
    }
}
```

This label will push the font forward a couple of points to prevent clipping.

Comment: Unfortunately the answer clearly takes the most time walking through exactly what I said don’t bother, as its already been done. It is a problem with the framework as I’ve pointed out. It’s clear I was asking for alternatives, and you gave them, but reluctantly. I appreciate your answer, and think it is well suited for most problems for many people in this area, but I don’t think it is appropriate for this question, so I’m going to down vote. Consider editing down to just the alternatives. If you think you missed something in my explanations, are curious to discuss things further, I’m open.

Comment: The steps laid out in my answer take minutes, not hours. Opting out of UILabel or hacking a solution would be much more time consuming and prone to break in any future OS update. For people looking for an alternative, like you, I stand by my answer because there is no attractive alternative.

Comment: I totally understand your point of view. As I would like very much to edit the font, but it’s not the font. Though just understand that it is a problem with a framework.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve similar problem with diacritics in Arabic and found workaround:

I have a UITableViewCell with UILabel with arabic text, it's diacritics were cut sometimes

I overrided `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)frame` to directly draw NSAttributedString on UITableViewCell

Also I decreased alpha `self.arabicLabel.alpha = 0.1;` to draw manually on top of label position, I still keep it to calculate cell's height

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)frame {
[super drawRect:frame];

if (self.viewModel == nil) return;
NSAttributedString *string = [self.viewModel arabicStringWithTajweed];

CGRect originalRect = [self convertRect:self.arabicLabel.frame fromView:self.arabicLabel];
[string drawInRect:originalRect];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The core problem on iOS is font substitution.  You are specifying a latin font, the font does not contain glyphs for the characters that will be rendered, the system uses a different font to draw the glyphs, but it is still measuring based on the original font.

Option 1, the most robust option, is to manually choose fonts that include glyphs for the characters you will render.  When the font assigned to UILabel, or the attributed string it is rendering, contains all the glyphs that will be rendered, and that font has good metrics as most system fonts do, then nothing will be clipped.

Option 2, manually measure the string using glyph bounds.  Make a subclass of UILabel and override `textRectForBounds` and possibly `drawText`.  Measure the string with `.usesDeviceMetrics`.  This is slower that measuring by font metrics and produces different results.  For example, the strings "a" and "A" will measure differently.

Option 3, use baseline offset and line height multiple to make room for the diacritics that are being clipped.  Choose or compute constant values for each font for each language, and apply those to the attributed string of the UILabel.  This can compensate for the different in font metrics between the font you chose and the font that is actually rendering glyphs.  We had localized strings with the worst case clipped characters for each language, and used those to compute the offset and height.  Different fonts have different worst case clipping characters.